# Two sets of rows in subsetting r

Tags: r, dataframe

In the iris data set, I would like to create a training data set of rows 1 to 10 and rows 21 to 150; and a test data set of rows 11 to 20.

Test is easy: `iris_test <- iris_n[11:20 ,]`

For the training set, I have tried `iris_train <- iris_n[1:10 & 21:150 , ]`

but I get an error message. I assume there is a simple way of doing it?

Comment: It should be `iris_n[c(1:10, 21:150) , ]`

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you should randomize your selection of the 10 rows like: `rows <- 1:nrow(iris_n); x <- sample(rows, size = 10); iris_test <- iris_n[x,]; iris_train <- iris_n[!(rows %in% x),]`

Comment: Alternatively, `iris_n[-c(11:20),]`

Answer (score 0):

As akrun suggested in the comment,

```
iris[c(1:10, 21:150) , ]
```

Also as desertnaut suggested:

```
iris[-c(11:20),]
```

I don't see the use of `_n` after `iris` in the above code.

> You should also try to mention what error you are getting (for future usage).